# get 5 highest value from foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop

I have done a code in foreach :

```
foreach ($queries as $record) {
    $total[] = $record->TotalTrans;
}
```

and from this record I wanted to determine top 5 results integer.

**Example of the results are :**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Transactions] => A
    [TotalTrans] => 2
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Transactions] => B
    [TotalTrans] => 95
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Transactions] => C
    [TotalTrans] => 5
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Transactions] => D
    [TotalTrans] => 12
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Transactions] => E
    [TotalTrans] => 4
)
```

is there a way to sort it in the foreach? thank you

Comment: First you convert object to array

Comment: Put your objects in an array and use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a custom sort function (see example at link).

Comment: Are all your objects in a array?is `$queries` this array?

Answer (score 3):

Use `usort` to sort your `$queries` array:

```
usort
(
    $queries,
    function( $a, $b )
    {
        return $b->TotalTrans > $a->TotalTrans;
    }
);
```

`usort` sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function: in your case, simply comparing `->TotalTrans` values.

Now you array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Transactions] => B
            [TotalTrans] => 95
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Transactions] => D
            [TotalTrans] => 12
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Transactions] => C
            [TotalTrans] => 5
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Transactions] => E
            [TotalTrans] => 4
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Transactions] => A
            [TotalTrans] => 2
        )
)
```

To retrieve only top 5 rows:

```
$topFive = array_slice( $queries, 0, 5 );
```

---

#### Edit:

With your `foreach()` loop, you can proceed in this way:

```
foreach ($queries as $record)
{
    $total[] = $record->TotalTrans;
}

rsort( $total );
$topFive = array_slice( $total, 0, 5 );
```

`rsort()` is a function to sort an array by value in reverse order.

---

- Read more about [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- Read more about [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- Read more about [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)